# Should I use window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, requestanimationframe

I am developing a game in JavaScript and I am confused on which one I should use -
`window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame` or `setInterval` for moving my game characters.

Comment: First, `window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame` is for WebKit browsers only. I guess you mean `requestAnimationFrame` in general. Second, did your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210920/why-speed-of-my-game-character-is-different-in-different-computers) not answer your concern?

Answer (score 2):

you can use window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval

```
var counter = 0;
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
var cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame ||
        window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame || window.oCancelAnimationFrame ||
        window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame || window.msCancelAnimationFrame;
var animation = function(){
        animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
        render();
}
animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
function render(){
        counter ++; 
        $('develement').css('-webkit-transform','translate3d(-'+counter+'px, 0, 0)');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what you try to do.

If you need to animate something in "real-time" (as in per frame) `requestAnimationFrame` is a better choice as it is able to sync to VBLANK of the monitor (via vsync on the gfx card) removing jerks. It's also more efficient and accurate.

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` are not able to sync to monitor refresh and are more costly on the system but are better to use if you only need occasional updates or when the delay is more than for example ~70 ms (or about 15 fps).

The `requestAnimationFrame` is no longer prefixed in Chrome or Firefox (older browsers/versions will need either prefix or a polyfill to work, see for example [this one](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) which also gives you more details on this topic). You don't need to specify the window object either.

Comment: Very well written. Loved the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should definitely use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of intervals.

As mentioned before, `setInterval` only guarantees that a certain function is put onto the JavaScript execution stack after a defined time. However, the *real* execution can be much later depending on the execution stack at that moment.

The best way (I know) for game animations is using `requestAnimationFrame` and doing your movement calculations based on the time that has elapsed since the last render and the new one.

mockup code:

```
function render(){
    var time_passed_since_last_render = Date.now() - window.last_render;
    window.last_render = Date.now()
    // do movements and collision checks here
    // movement distance calculations are based on 'time_passed_since_last_render'
}

while (playerStillAlive) {
    // do things such as checking for input (keyboard push etc.)
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webkitRequestAnimationFrame
```

It's preferable to the timeout which is `windows.setTimeout(fun,millisecond)` functions because you're asking the browser to call your function whenever it has available resources, not after a predefined time in milliseconds.

Be aware that scheduling a function in some amount of milliseconds is not a guarantee
that it will execute exactly at that time. One reason is that most browsers don't have
millisecond resolution time. If you schedule something in 3 milliseconds, it will
execute after a minimum of 15 in older IEs and sooner in more modern browsers, but
most likely not in 1 millisecond. The other reason is that browsers maintain a queue
of what you request them to do. 100 milliseconds timeout means add to the queue
after 100 milliseconds. But if the queue is delayed by something slow happening, your
function will have to wait and execute after, say, 120 milliseconds.