# How can I slow down my animation using the requestAnimationFrame() in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, requestanimationframe

Right now I am coding Conway's game of life in JavaScript, the problem I'm having is with my animation using the requestAnimationFrame(). When I load the game in the browser the animation runs too quickly in a blink. I'm wondering if anyone can offer any suggestions, on how I can slow down the animation so that it is visible to see it running correctly?

The Javascript code is as follows:

```js
$(function(event) {

    var GRIDWIDTH = 400;
    var GRIDHEIGHT = 400;
    var gameGrid = createGrid(GRIDWIDTH); //Grid used to display the grid
    var newGameGrid = createGrid(GRIDWIDTH); //Grid used to update game state

    //creates the grid for the game, using an array of empty arrays
    function createGrid(rows) {
      var gridArray = []; //is the game grid
      //for loop that creates the grid array, each element is an empty array to create the multi-dimensional array
      for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        gridArray[i] = [];
      }
    return gridArray;
    }

    //will populate the grid randomly with alive and dead cells
    function populateGrid() {
      for (var rows = 0; rows < GRIDHEIGHT; rows++) { //goes across the rows within the grid
        for (var cols = 0; cols < GRIDWIDTH; cols++) { //goes across the columns within the grid
            var cell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 ); //the cells of the grid is either a 1 or 0 (alive or dead), chosen at random
            if (cell === 1) { //if the cell variable is the same as the integer value 1 and same type int then the element at gameGrid[rows][cols] is set to a 1 else a 0, this is done randomly.
            gameGrid[rows][cols] = 1;
          }
            else {
            gameGrid[rows][cols] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //Will draw the game grid on the screen including cells
    function drawGrid() {
      // var gameCanvas = $("#gameCanvas"); //gets the gameCanvas element
      var ctx = $("#gameCanvas")[0].getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
      //both loops go through the rows and columns respectively and draws the pixel in the grid in the specified colour
      for (var rows = 1; rows < GRIDHEIGHT; rows++) {
        for (var cols = 1; cols < GRIDWIDTH; cols++) {
          if (gameGrid[rows][cols] === 1) { //if the element is a 1 the pixel is coloured (red) to represent it is alive
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(rows, cols, 1, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //this function will update the grid to show the new position of the pixels
    function updateGrid() {
      for (var rows = 1; rows < GRIDHEIGHT - 1; rows++) {
        for (var cols = 1; cols < GRIDWIDTH - 1; cols++) {
          var totalNeighbours = 0; //holds the total neighbours a cell has
          //calculations to add the neighbours
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows-1][cols-1]; //top left
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows-1][cols]; //top center
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows-1][cols+1] //top right

          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows][cols-1] //middle left
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows][cols+1] //middle right

          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows+1][cols-1] //bottom left
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows+1][cols] //bottom center
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows+1][cols+1] //bottom right

          //Game of life rules:

          //alive cell rules
          if (gameGrid[rows][cols] === 1) {
            switch(totalNeighbours) {
              //rule 1 any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if by underpopulation
              case totalNeighbours < 2:
                newGameGrid[rows][cols] = 0;
                break;
              //rule 2 any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation
              case totalNeighbours == 2:
              case totalNeighbours == 3:
                newGameGrid[rows][cols] = 1;
                break;
              //rule 3 any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation
              case totalNeighbours > 3:
                newGameGrid[rows][cols] = 0;
                break;
            }
          }
          //dead cell rule 4 any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction
          else if (gameGrid[rows][cols] === 0) {
            if (totalNeighbours == 3) {
              newGameGrid[rows][cols] = 1;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        //iterate through the rows and columns and gameGrid is set to the newGameGrid with the updated cells in the grid
        for (var rows = 0; rows < GRIDWIDTH; rows++) {
          for (var cols = 0; cols < GRIDHEIGHT; cols++) {
            gameGrid[rows][cols] = newGameGrid[rows][cols];
          }
        }
      }

      populateGrid();
      start();
      function start() {
        drawGrid();
        updateGrid();
        requestAnimationFrame(start);
      }

    })
```

```html
The html is simple as follows:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Conway's Game Of Life</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="gameScreen">
      <div class="title">John Conway's Game Of Life</div>
      <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

also see

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250687/should-i-use-window-webkitrequestanimationframe-instead-of-setinterval/54795256#54795256)

I think you should use the time elapsed between renders combined with a speed factor.

For example you could define that you want your main character to move 200px in one second. Then - using the elapsed time between renders you can calculate how far you want to move him (mockup code):

```
var distance_to_move = 200px * time_since_last_render / 1000;
setNewPosition();
render();
```

So if your time passed since last render is exaclty 500ms then in this render you will move him 100px.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use `requestAnimationFrame`: the function you pass to it accepts one argument which is the timestamp. You can use it to calculate time passed. In this example, the step is set to 2s (2000ms). Note that you need to start with `requestAnimationFrame(start);` instead of `start();`:

```js
$(function(event) {

    var GRIDWIDTH = 400;
    var GRIDHEIGHT = 400;
    var gameGrid = createGrid(GRIDWIDTH); //Grid used to display the grid
    var newGameGrid = createGrid(GRIDWIDTH); //Grid used to update game state

    //creates the grid for the game, using an array of empty arrays
    function createGrid(rows) {
      var gridArray = []; //is the game grid
      //for loop that creates the grid array, each element is an empty array to create the multi-dimensional array
      for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        gridArray[i] = [];
      }
      return gridArray;
    }

    //will populate the grid randomly with alive and dead cells
    function populateGrid() {
      for (var rows = 0; rows < GRIDHEIGHT; rows++) { //goes across the rows within the grid
        for (var cols = 0; cols < GRIDWIDTH; cols++) { //goes across the columns within the grid
            var cell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 ); //the cells of the grid is either a 1 or 0 (alive or dead), chosen at random
            if (cell === 1) { //if the cell variable is the same as the integer value 1 and same type int then the element at gameGrid[rows][cols] is set to a 1 else a 0, this is done randomly.
            gameGrid[rows][cols] = 1;
          }
            else {
            gameGrid[rows][cols] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //Will draw the game grid on the screen including cells
    function drawGrid() {
      // var gameCanvas = $("#gameCanvas"); //gets the gameCanvas element
      var ctx = $("#gameCanvas")[0].getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
      //both loops go through the rows and columns respectively and draws the pixel in the grid in the specified colour
      for (var rows = 1; rows < GRIDHEIGHT; rows++) {
        for (var cols = 1; cols < GRIDWIDTH; cols++) {
          if (gameGrid[rows][cols] === 1) { //if the element is a 1 the pixel is coloured (red) to represent it is alive
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(rows, cols, 1, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //this function will update the grid to show the new position of the pixels
    function updateGrid() {
      for (var rows = 1; rows < GRIDHEIGHT - 1; rows++) {
        for (var cols = 1; cols < GRIDWIDTH - 1; cols++) {
          var totalNeighbours = 0; //holds the total neighbours a cell has
          //calculations to add the neighbours
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows-1][cols-1]; //top left
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows-1][cols]; //top center
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows-1][cols+1] //top right

          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows][cols-1] //middle left
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows][cols+1] //middle right

          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows+1][cols-1] //bottom left
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows+1][cols] //bottom center
          totalNeighbours += gameGrid[rows+1][cols+1] //bottom right

          //Game of life rules:

          //alive cell rules
          if (gameGrid[rows][cols] === 1) {
            switch(totalNeighbours) {
              //rule 1 any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if by underpopulation
              case totalNeighbours < 2:
                newGameGrid[rows][cols] = 0;
                break;
              //rule 2 any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation
              case totalNeighbours == 2:
              case totalNeighbours == 3:
                newGameGrid[rows][cols] = 1;
                break;
              //rule 3 any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation
              case totalNeighbours > 3:
                newGameGrid[rows][cols] = 0;
                break;
            }
          }
          //dead cell rule 4 any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction
          else if (gameGrid[rows][cols] === 0) {
            if (totalNeighbours == 3) {
              newGameGrid[rows][cols] = 1;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        //iterate through the rows and columns and gameGrid is set to the newGameGrid with the updated cells in the grid
        for (var rows = 0; rows < GRIDWIDTH; rows++) {
          for (var cols = 0; cols < GRIDHEIGHT; cols++) {
            gameGrid[rows][cols] = newGameGrid[rows][cols];
          }
        }
      }

      populateGrid();
      requestAnimationFrame(start);

      var startTime = null, stepInMs = 2000, drawCount = 0;
      function start(timestamp) {
          var progress;
          if (startTime === null){
              startTime = timestamp;
          }
          progress = timestamp - startTime;
          if (progress > stepInMs) {
              drawCount++;
              document.getElementById('drawCount').innerHTML = drawCount;
              startTime = timestamp;
              drawGrid();
              updateGrid();
          }
          requestAnimationFrame(start);
      }

    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Conway's Game Of Life</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="gameScreen">
      <div class="title">John Conway's Game Of Life - count: <span id="drawCount">0</span></div>
      <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: added a span to show redraws with a count to demonstrate, there might be something wrong in your code as it only changes 2 times while it gets redrawn..