# Java Game Animations are very slow and unclear

Tags: java, animation, position

In my Java Game, which should get an AirForce, i have simple moving animations, for the player, the missiles, and the enemys.

My Problem is, these Animations are very slow. Not slow as usual, but it seems like the animation happens, and the programme is waiting for something.. but what - i dont know. 
Also it isnt the sleep time - when i reduce it, it shows the same but faster. 
so mooooooove - stop - moooooooove - stop, and this very fast.

So, here the important code, where i move the JPanels: (which are containing the pictures)

```
public void run(){
    while(running){
        if(!pause){
            System.out.println(timeSinceLastFrame);
            updateTimes();
            handleMissiles();
            handlePlayer();
            handleEnemys();
            repaint();
            try{Thread.sleep(10);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
}

public void updateTimes(){
    thisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timeSinceLastFrame = ((float) (thisFrame-lastFrame)/1000f);
    lastFrame=thisFrame;
    timeSinceLastMissile++;
}

public void handleMissiles(){
    for(int i = 0; i < missiles.size(); i++){
        Missile m = missiles.get(i);
        m.setX((int) (m.getX() * 1.02 + 1));
        m.resetPosition();
        if(m.isUnused()){
            gameField.remove(m);
            missiles.remove(m);
        }
    }
}

public void handlePlayer(){
    if(flyUp){ player.fly(0); } 
    if(flyRight){ player.fly(1); }
    if(flyDown){ player.fly(2); }
    if(flyLeft){ player.fly(3); }
    if(shoot){ shoot(); }
}

public void handleEnemys(){
    for(int i = 0; i < enemys.size(); i++){
        Enemy e = enemys.get(i);
        e.setX((int) (e.getX() - e.speedX));
        e.resetPosition();
        if(e.isDestroyed()){
            gameField.remove(e);
            enemys.remove(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The player fly method looks like this:

```
public void fly(int dir){
    switch(dir){
        case 0: flyUp(); break;
        case 1: flyRight(); break;
        case 2: flyDown(); break;
        case 3: flyLeft(); break;
    }
    resetPosition();
}

public void flyUp(){
    if(y > 0){
        setY(getY() - 3);
    }
}
public void flyRight(){
    if(x < frameWidth - width - 10){
        setX(getX() + 3);
    }
}   
public void flyDown(){
    if(y < frameHeight - height - 30){
        setY(getY() + 3);
    }
}   
public void flyLeft(){
    if(x > 0){
        setX(getX() - 3);
    }
}
```

Reset position is nothing special:

```
public void resetPosition(){
    setBounds(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Note that the gamelogic itself also takes time to be executed. Check this answer for how to write a gameloop that works around this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210920/why-speed-of-my-game-character-is-different-in-different-computers#answer-16211284

Comment: Try `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `Thread.sleep`

Comment: Why timer is better? Is there anywhere an thread about it?

Comment: Is this using Swing, AWT, SWT, GWT, Android, ..? For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And +1 to @SeniorJD suggestion.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.